# В bootstrap datepicker V4 неправильно работает выбор месяца

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datepicker

Имеется инпут:

```
<input type="text" name="filter" class="form-control" id="date"/>
```

И js для него:

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: "months",
    format: "M.YYYY",
});
```

При первом нажатии на input скрипт отрабатывает нормально: можно выбрать месяц и год.
При втором нажатии на input (если страница не была перезагружена) выпадает обычный календарь с днями, месяцами и годами.

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом нажатии на input выпадал выбор месяца и года?

Comment: Возможно бред скажу, а формат правильно записан? там не 2 `M` должно быть?

Comment: С форматом проблем нет. Первый раз календарь правильно отрабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему!
Оказывается, что данный баг - это баг последних версий Bootstrap Datepicker (4.17.42 и 4.17.43).
Для корректной работы нужно **скачать**

```
Bootstrap Datepicker версии 4.17.37
```

При этом также необходимо использовать

```
Jquery версии 2.1.4
```

или ниже, так как Datepicker версии 4.17.37 не может работать с Jquery 3.0+